# Unable to load texture in C# OpenGL

Tags: c#, opengl

I am working through C# Game Programming for Serious Game creation and I appear to have hit a wall.

The following code does not seem to work. ie openGLId returns 0.

The texure seems to load from disk ok. But no Id is attached to it.

```
public void LoadTexture(string textureId, string path)
    {
        int devilId = 0;             
        Il.ilGenImages(1, out devilId);              
        Il.ilBindImage(devilId); // set as the active texture.
        if (!Il.ilLoadImage(path))
        {                  
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false,"Could not open file, [" + path + "].");
        }               

        Ilu.iluFlipImage();
        int width = Il.ilGetInteger(Il.IL_IMAGE_WIDTH);
        int height = Il.ilGetInteger(Il.IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
        int openGLId = Ilut.ilutGLBindTexImage();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(openGLId != 0);
        Il.ilDeleteImages(1, ref devilId);

        _textureDatabase.Add(textureId, new Texture(openGLId, width, height, path));
    }
```

Is there a better way to load an OpenGL texture?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I might have the answer for you.

This is my class to load a texture with devIL libs.

```
public class TextureLoader
{
    int texid;
    bool success;

    int image;
    int width;
    int height;

    string path;

    public TextureLoader(string path)
    {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public void display()
    {
        Il.ilInit();
        Il.ilGenImages(1, out texid);
        Il.ilBindImage(texid);

        success = Il.ilLoadImage(path);

        if (success)
        {
            success = Il.ilConvertImage(Il.IL_RGBA, Il.IL_UNSIGNED_BYTE);

            if (!success)
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR");

            width = Il.ilGetInteger(Il.IL_IMAGE_WIDTH);
            height = Il.ilGetInteger(Il.IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT);

            Gl.glGenTextures(1, out image);
            Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, image);
            Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);
            Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);
            Gl.glTexImage2D(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,
                Il.ilGetInteger(Il.IL_IMAGE_BPP),
                Il.ilGetInteger(Il.IL_IMAGE_WIDTH),
                Il.ilGetInteger(Il.IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT), 0,
                Il.ilGetInteger(Il.IL_IMAGE_FORMAT), Gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                Il.ilGetData()
                );
        }

        Il.ilDeleteImage(texid);

        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); Gl.glVertex2f(-width / 2.0f, height / 2.0f);
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); Gl.glVertex2f(-width / 2.0f, height / 2.0f);
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(1, 1); Gl.glVertex2f(1, -1);
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(1, 0); Gl.glVertex2f(1, 1);
        Gl.glEnd();
        Gl.glFlush();

        Gl.glDeleteTextures(1, ref image);
    }
}
```

The code is not commented, but is not complex. With this class i can load png and jpg images.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I had to change the quad drawing because it did not draw the quad properly:             Gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); Gl.glVertex2f(-1.0f, -1.0f);
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); Gl.glVertex2f(1.0f, -1.0f);
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); Gl.glVertex2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
            Gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); Gl.glVertex2f(-1.0f, 1.0f); Unfortunately This code did not work for me. It did not report any errors and the file loaded OK. But the texture did not show up.